# Testing an multipart form HTTP POST from my iOS app

Tags: php, ios, forms

I'm finishing an app that sends data as a multipart HTTP POST to a server.

Problem is that said server is not available yet, and I want a sort of 'dummy' server to set up that can receive an HTTP POST request like that and just store/spit out the end result so I can see what I'm sending.

I have a host and know my way around a web server, but I never had to deal with a situation like this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a web proxy to verify that what you sent is correct. I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Charles can also be setup to return fake responses.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to set up a server on your host and any php frameworks to get http requests such as [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)